# PDO Creation Fails when Connecting to Remote MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, exception, pdo

My friend and I are working on a website, and I am trying to install a build of it on my machine. It is already running live on the server, I just can't seem to connect from my local machine. When I do I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] 
Access denied for user 'myusername'@'adsl-client.example.net' (using password: YES)' in /Users/myname/Sites/mysitefolder/req/connect.php:25 
Stack trace: #0 /Users/myname/Sites/mysitefolder/req/connect.php(25): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'myusername', 'mypassword') 
#1 /Users/myname/Sites/burn-after-reading/inc/header.php(9): ConnectionFactory->getConnection() 
#2 /Users/myname/Sites/burn-after-reading/index.php(79): include('/Users/myna...') 
#3 {main} thrown in /Users/myname/Sites/mysitefolder/req/connect.php on line 25
```

Here is the file I am trying to connect from, connect.php

```
<?php

class ConnectionFactory
{
    var $dbhost = 'mysql.mysitename.io';
    var $dbname = 'my_database_name';
    var $dbusername = 'myusername';
    var $dbpassword = 'mypassword';

    private static $factory;
    public static function getFactory()
    {
        if (!self::$factory)
            self::$factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        return self::$factory;
    }

    public function getConnection() 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}", 
            $this->dbusername,
            $this->dbpassword);
        return $conn;
    }

    public function getConnectionNoName()
    {
        $connNoName = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->dbhost}", 
            $this->dbusername,
            $this->dbpassword
        );
        return $connNoName;
    }
}
```

Comment: who is your host? you might need to give permission mysql to accept external connection

Comment: Typically when performing a remote connection to a mysql server you need to have an `@ipaddress` following your username and the IP needs to be added as an allowable remote connection source, much as @meda said

Comment: @meda That was it, thank you! Had to add our IP address to the MySQL accepted connections list.

Comment: In this case, the exception message tells you exactly what you need to know.  You either don't have right credentials for the user/hostname specified, or you don't have a user account with proper access configured.

Answer (score -1):

For security reason you need to add your IP address to the list of allowed remote  `mysql` connections.

Comment: this answer is correct as you can see in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096592/pdo-creation-fails-when-connecting-to-remote-mysql-server/23096785#comment35304114_23096592) yet again you wrongfully downvote it, this goes against the rules of this community

Comment: It is not matter of correctness. It is matter of abusing vote system.

Comment: well by downvoting correct answer you are indeed abusing the vote system, thats clearly a misuse

Comment: Nope, I am not. I am free to vote anything I wish. I am talking of not my votes though, but someone else's.

Comment: You are free to vote , thats right but you cannot target me for downvotes and say you are free to do so, that's the wrong part.

Comment: I am not targeting you. I am targeting your sock puppets.

Comment: `I am talking of not my votes` so you aknowledge your downvotes are not legitimate.

Comment: Do not pretend you don't understand me. I am talking of your sock puppets' votes. It doesn't matter though. As you aren't going to delete them, we'll ask someone to help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense lolll I started to think you have mental problems, go ahead please